# switch off circuit when below 0.7 - 1V - UVLO?

Tags: diodes, micropower

I would like to create a undervoltage lockout that switches off power from a low voltage section of a circuit when the supply is below 0.7 - 1V.

As I understand it, most very low voltage logic stops having defined states at 0.6V or so. Presumably this follows that a circuit that only switches on at above these levels will still have an undefined state at below these levels. In this circuit it may take many seconds to go from 0V to above 0.7V. During this period I would ideally like to prevent any power being used by the rest of the circuit.

Does anyone have any creative suggestions or pointers?

EDIT: Thank you for all of the replies so far. To clarify:

- The circuit being cut off is also being powered by the same supply. I'm after a 'gatekeeper' circuit to stop power going to the rest of the circuit when Vin < 0.7 - 1V.
- The rest of the circuit will use a maximum of 100mA @ < 1.8V.
- Ideally it would be a high side switch (but can work with low side)
- I also forgot to add (very important) - the 'gatekeeper' part of the circuit shouldn't use more than a few microamps!

Comment: You could easily use a comparator, an RS latch and a MOSFET working from a higher voltage  to switch to shut the lower voltage circuit down,  But under what conditions would you like to have the lower voltage circuit be turned back ON?

Comment: A P channel JFET might do the trick depending on the pinch-off voltage; it won't be very accurate but might suffice.

Comment: Are you interested in a high-side or a low-side switching solution?

Comment: Also, how much current are you trying to switch?

Comment: A lot of details are missing. But you could probably use an NPN BJT + a PMOS high-side switch.

Comment: @EMFields There is only one power source. So there is an incoming power source that will vary from 0 - 1.8V. I would like a 'gatekeeper' circuit to prevent any power going to the rest of the circuit until the incoming / supply voltage is above 0.7 - 1V or so.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ideally high side and 100mA or so. Can't use more than a few microamps.

Comment: Interesting question to me. One thing that crosses my mind is hysteresis in the thresholds. You'll need something. I'm assuming you don't care right now because you don't even know what solutions are out there. But it remains important to consider. 100mV band? More, or less? Either way, interesting question.

Comment: Best I can do with three BJTs is a solid LOW starting at 0.4V and holding LOW until 0.8V (that can be adjusted.) Before (and after some set point) output tracks the supply rail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not asking for the impossible!  While traditional SVS chips are available for such low voltages and within your power budget, their outputs are undefined at very low voltages, which isn't very helpful for your cause here.

Fortunately, some smart folks at Advanced Linear Devices came up with a way to make a precision-threshold-voltage MOSFET device using the same floating-gate technology that is the basis of the EEPROM and Flash chips we all know.  The result is what they call an EPAD™ -- a FET that basically can act as a comparator of sorts, with much greater precision than the order-of-magnitude Vgs(th) range on a typical MOSFET.  The resulting circuit is disarmingly simple, and shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7CjJq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 is the ALD110908 dual N-channel EPAD in SO-8 with a factory-programmed 0.8V Vgs(th) -- both sections are connected in parallel, which means that pins 2 and 7 of the SO-8 are connected to Vin, 3 and 6 are connected to R1 and the gate of Q2, and 1, 4, 5, and 8 all go to GND as the substrate on the EPADs is pinned out separately.  Q2 is an AO3435 P-channel power FET in SOT-23 -- it was specified due to its maximum gate leakage current of 100nA.  R1 is not particularly critical in value -- 10MΩ was chosen as it is the most common resistor value large enough for Q1's pullup in this circuit.  If the resistor value isn't a dead giveaway, by the way, this is a high-impedance circuit and needs to be constructed with low-leakage techniques:

- No-clean is a no-no, and so are grubby fingerprints on the board
- A good quality PCB substrate should be used
- Topside copper fills should be kept clear of the circuit area
- Layout should be compact and direct

Comment: The only problem is Q2 may have excessive RdsOn at 1V to pass 100mA. It is rated for 1.5V but not 1V.  A bit more searching might find a better one than my result  PHK04P02T rated for 0.8V

Comment: @TonyStewart -- sadly, NXP failed when they went to spec that part -- the Vgs(th) max isn't specified

Comment: My PHK04P02T  has Vgs = -0.4 min , -0.6 nom    while  graphs show data from Vgs >=0.8V only suggests they don't test for this max but it will be somewhere between -0.7 and -0.8V whereas AO3435  has a Vgs = -1.5V nom is too much

Comment: You have a point insofar that the AO3435 does have a max Vgs(th) of -1.0V -- but with NXP's remiss behavior in not specifying a max Vgs(th) for the PHK04P02T...guess I'll have to do some more searching around then

Comment: yes something with <1Ohm RdsOn at Vgs=1V to 0.7V or use a low side Nch , since this must be a battery operation.

Comment: I think something EPAD based is likely the answer. Awesome technology.

Answer (score 2):

The Schottky diode raises the Vin threshold to 1V.. P-FET has Vgs=1V.
Add caps to suit ripple and delay needs.

- V Threshold might be 0.8 to 0.9V
- Rev A for < few uA bias current.

[image: schematic]

RdsOn @1V needs to be verified.
Rev A above after spec added for few uA idle current max and 100mA peak load.
.
                     - ~ -  original below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqSa6W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The supply is also the voltage being monitored so that P type mosfet would likely leak when coming close to the 0.7V threshold if UV in and V+ in were connected. Additinally, I only have a power budget of a few microamps. I may be asking for the impossible...

Comment: 1uA at what voltages

Comment: YOu will probably need another supply to sense/disable this "unknown circuit"

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought and not tested (so constructive critisms only please) but how about something like this.

[image]

Here's my thinking:

Below about 1.2V diodes D2,D3 can't conduct and so any voltage lower than that is not seen at the output. Note that this is not meant to be the lower limit voltage.

D1 and Q1 base-emitter form a voltage drop of about 0.8V  (the lower limit voltage). A voltage above that would turn on Q1 (NPN BJT) with a suitable value of R1.

If Q1 is ON then Q2 (PNP BJT) is also ON with base current controlled by R2. (Q1 collector-emitter in saturation, say 0.1V)

Q2 has a drop of about 0.1V between collector-emitter (in saturation) and effectively shorts out the diode drops leaving Vout about 0.1V less than Vin for input voltages greater than about 0.8V.

If Vin drops below 0.8v Q1 is turned OFF, Q2 is turned OFF leaving only the two diodes, D2, D3 in circuit which prevent this low voltage getting through, so Vout = 0V

Comment: You have understood what I was after perfectly. I need to think this through but it appears promising. The intention of this circuit is what I was after.

The requirement of this is to prevent other IC's after this point operating in an 'unknown state' (< 0.7V), potentially leaking current when they're not supposed to.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of emitter-base leakage through Q1 sending his Iq outta whack -- jellybean BJTs are specified for Iebo/Ibex at a reverse bias of a few volts, not with an E-B short or worse yet with a low voltage "dancing" on the base with respect to the emitter, and the Schottky can't do anything about it as it likely leaks more than the BJT.